# Manually set needs_recovery flag in ext4 filesystem to True

Tags: filesystems, ext4

I am trying to setup some unit tests for an application, and one thing I need is a 'dirty' ext4 filesystem that can be tested against. Is there a way I can manually set the 'needs_recovery' flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tune2fs` to alter the `max-mount-counts` and/or `mount-count` to suit your needs.

For example, setting `max-mount-counts` to `1` (issuing `tune2fs -c 1 /dev/sdX`) would cause a complete `fsck` to run each time you mount your filesystem.

For more information, [read the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs):

> **-c max-mount-counts** Adjust the number of mounts after which the filesystem will be checked by e2fsck(8). If max-mount-counts is 0 or
>   -1, the number of times the filesystem is mounted will be disregarded by e2fsck(8) and the kernel. Staggering the mount-counts at which
>   filesystems are forcibly checked will avoid all filesystems being
>   checked at one time when using journaled filesystems.
>
> ...
>
> See also the -i option for time-dependent checking.
>
> **-C mount-count** Set the number of times the filesystem has been mounted. If set to a greater value than the max-mount-counts parameter
>   set by the -c option, e2fsck(8) will check the filesystem at the next
>   reboot.